# SQL - condition for each record in bundle

Tags: sql, row, bundle, each

I have problem with this select. If anybody help, it would be great:

There are tables called `BUNDLE, COURSE and BUNDLE_COURSE`

The `BUNDLE` contain information like `price, discount` etc.
The `COURSE` contain information like `title, icon_path` etc.

The `BUNDLE_COURSE` table is link table and one bundle contain more `COURSES`.

Example:

```
BUNDLE  | BUNDLE_COURSE| COURSE
--------+--------------+----------
1       | 1,5          | 5
2       | 1,6          | 6
        | 1,7          | 7
        | 2,5          | 8
        | 2,7          |
        | 2,8          |
```

I need to get only BUNDLES, where all COURSES meet conditions
(**For example**: `course_date > CURRENT_DATE`)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select all bundles where no course exists that does not meet the criteria:

```
select  *
from    bundles b
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    courses c
        where   c.id = b.course
                and course_date < getdate() -- Note inverse condition
                and ...
        )
```

A good article on this is [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using aggregation and a `having` clause.  Here is an example using your condition:

```
select b.bundleid
from bundle b join
     bundle_course bc
     on b.bundleid = bc.bundleid join
     course c
     on bc.courseid = c.courseid
group by b.bundleid
having min(c.coursedate) >= CURRENT_DATE;
```

If you wanted to add more conditions, that is easy.  For instance, if you wanted bundles with the above condition and at least three courses:

```
having min(c.coursedate) >= CURRENT_DATE and
       count(*) >= 3;
```

If you wanted at least one course to have the word "SQL" in the title:

```
having min(c.coursedate) >= CURRENT_DATE and
       count(*) >= 3 and
       sum(case when c.title like '%SQL%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```